# Retrofit service is always null after adding Interceptor and injecting it using Dagger2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, dagger-2, okhttp

I have a relogin retrofit service like this

```
interface TokenService {
    @GET("re-login")
    fun relogin(): Call<ReloginResponse>
}
```

Then I have a `NetModule` where all the dependencies are injected like this

```
@Module
class NetModule(baseUrl: String) {
    var baseUrl = baseUrl
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGson(): Gson {
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        return gsonBuilder.create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkhttp(tokenInterceptor: TokenInterceptor): OkHttpClient {

        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
//                .authenticator(tokenAutheticator)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)

                .build()

        return client
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTokenHoler():TokenHolder{
        return TokenHolder()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTokenService(retrofit: Retrofit,tokenHolder: TokenHolder):TokenService{
        val tokenService = retrofit.create(TokenService::class.java)
        tokenHolder.tokenService = tokenService
        return tokenService
    }

}
```

Then `TokenHolder` class is like this

```
class TokenHolder {
    var tokenService:TokenService?=null
        get() = field
        set(value) {field=value}
}
```

And this is the `TokenInterceptor` class where I am getting `null` in the TokenService part.

```
@Singleton
class TokenInterceptor @Inject constructor(private val tokenHolder: TokenHolder) :Interceptor{
    var token:String=""
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val original = chain.request()
        val originalHttpUrl = original.url()

        val url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("token", token)
                .build()

        // Request customization: add request headers
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .url(url)

        val request = requestBuilder.build()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)

        if(response.code()==401){

            val newToken = tokenHolder.tokenService?.relogin()?.execute()?.body()?.token

            val url1 = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("token", newToken)
                    .build()
            println("########## new new token ########## "+newToken)//this is null
            // Request customization: add request headers
            val requestBuilder1 = original.newBuilder()
                    .url(url1)

            val request1 = requestBuilder1.build()
            val response1 = chain.proceed(request1)
            return response1
        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

I am trying to hit Relogin after I get the `401` response but I always get  `TokenService` null. How should I provide the dependencies? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `TokenService` should be dependency of `provideTokenHoler()` (not the other way around)

Comment: try `return response`

Comment: @Blackbelt that way I get the cyclic dependency error

Comment: if you keep both of course you will create a cicle. But you do not need `,tokenHolder: TokenHolder` as dependency for `provideTokenService, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see `TokenHolder` has null instance of `TokenService`, because there is no way to pass it there. You are creating instance of TokenService via Dagger and passing it to TokenHolder, but it is not the same instance you are getting inside interceptor. You should invert your dependencies. Update module methods to this and tell me if it works.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideTokenHolder(service:TokenService): TokenHolder{
    return TokenHolder(service)
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideTokenService(retrofit: Retrofit): TokenService{
    return retrofit.create(TokenService::class.java)
}
```

TokenService as a null should not happen so you should declare TokenHolder as below.

```
class TokenHolder(val service: TokenService)
```

Furthermore to break your dependency circle. You have to change TokenInterceptor declaration.

```
class TokenInterceptor @Inject constructor(private val tokenHolder: Lazy<TokenHolder>) : Interceptor
```

Wrap TokenHolder with Dagger.Lazy and it should do a job.

Comment: I am getting cyclic dependency error because of Retrofit being injected there and then the Interceptor is being injected in Okhttp

Comment: Could you attach stacktrace?

Comment: retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
          com.pkg.di.module.NetModule.provideTokenService(retrofit)
      com.pkg.token.TokenService is injected at
          com.pkg.di.module.NetModule.provideTokenHolder(service)
      com.pkg.token.TokenHolder is injected at
          com.pkg.utils.TokenInterceptor.<init>(tokenHolder)
      com.pkg.utils.TokenInterceptor is injected at
          com.pkg.di.module.NetModule.provideOkhttp(tokenInterceptor)
      okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
          com.pkg.di.module.NetModule.provideRetrofit(…, okHttpClient)
      retrofit2.Retrofit is inj

Comment: I hope that's understandable

Comment: Could you tell me what is the point of TokenHolder? Won't be easier to just inject TokenService instead of it?

Comment: This stacktrace looks like it indeed is dependency circle. We should figure out a way to redesign it.

Comment: It would be easier to directly inject TokenService but even then there is cyclic dependency

Comment: I prepared project like this to test it and I figured out an answear. I added one more step to my answear. Recheck and retest please.